# Why does `gcc -ffast-math` disable the correct result of `isnan()` and `isinf()`?

Tags: c, gcc, isnan

I understand that using the [`-ffast-math`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) flag allows for unsafe math operations and disables signalling NaNs. However, I expected the functions `isnan()` and `isinf()` to still be able to return the correct results, which they do not.

Here's an example:

File `test_isnan.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void){

  /* Produce a NaN */
  const float my_nan = sqrtf(-1.f);
  /* Produce an inf */
  const float my_inf = 1.f/0.f;

  printf("This should be a NaN: %.6e\n", my_nan);
  printf("This should be inf: %.6e\n", my_inf);

  if (isnan(my_nan)) {
    printf("Caugth the nan!\n");
  } else {
    printf("isnan failed?\n");
  }

  if (isinf(my_inf)) {
    printf("Caugth the inf!\n");
  } else {
    printf("isinf failed?\n");
  }
}
```

Now let's compile and run the program without `-ffast-math`:

```
$ gcc test_isnan.c -lm -o test_isnan.o && ./test_isnan.o
This should be a NaN: -nan
This should be inf: inf
Caugth the nan!
Caugth the inf!
```

But with it:

```
$ gcc test_isnan.c -lm -o test_isnan.o -ffast-math && ./test_isnan.o
This should be a NaN: -nan
This should be inf: inf
isnan failed?
isinf failed?
```

So why don't `isnan()` and `isinf()` catch these `nan`s and `inf`s? What am I missing?

In case it might be relevant, here's my `gcc` version:

```
gcc (Spack GCC) 10.2.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html:

> -ffast-math
> Sets the options -fno-math-errno, -funsafe-math-optimizations, **-ffinite-math-only**, -fno-rounding-math, -fno-signaling-nans, -fcx-limited-range and -fexcess-precision=fast.

Where:

> -ffinite-math-only
> Allow optimizations for floating-point arithmetic that **assume that arguments and results are not NaNs or +-Infs**.

The moment you break that assumption, you can't expect those functions to work.

I understand that you were hoping for this setting to optimize all the other operations while still providing a correct result for these two functions, but that's just not the way it works. I don't think there's a way to solve this. Maybe you can have a look at Clang, but I don't expect it to be different.

Comment: "Allow optimizations for floating-point arithmetic": 
I didn't know `isnan` and `isinf` would be arithmetic...?

Comment: Why wouldn't they? It's true that they do not *compute* a value, if that's what you mean, but they still *work* with one.

Comment: `-ffast-math -fno-finite-math-only` gives the desired behavior.

Answer (score 2):

> -ffast-math
>
> Sets the options ... -ffinite-math-only ...

> -ffinite-math-only
>
> Allow optimizations for floating-point arithmetic that assume that arguments and **results are not NaNs** or +-Infs.

Compiler optimizes the code to:

```
  printf("This should be a NaN: %.6e\n", sqrtf(-1.f));
  printf("This should be inf: %.6e\n", 1.f/0.f);
  printf("isnan failed?\n");
  printf("isinf failed?\n");
```

because the compiler knows that expressions can't return `nan` or `inf`.

Comment: Same comment as with the other answer: Why are `isnan` and `isinf` considered arithmetic..?

Comment: I do not undersatnd. It's not that `isnan` is arithmetic, `sqrtf` is. Compiler assumes that `sqrtf` __can't__ return `nan`, so it optimizes `isnan` out.

Comment: The problem is that this remains even if reading e.g. a nan from the outside world: `double* ptr = (double*)mmap(...); if(!isnan(*ptr)) { /* proceed with business logic which expects no NaNs*/ }` also does not work.